# TypeError: Movie() takes no arguments

Tags: python, классы

```
class Movie:
    def __int__(self, name, year):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year

matrix = Movie('the Matrix', 1999)
print(matrix)
```

Comment: Чтобы класс принимал аргументы, нужно создать метод `__init__`, а в вашем коде такого метода нет

Comment: Исправьте `__int__` на `__init___`